# Something amiss with some incanter functions

Tags: clojure, incanter

While usng Incanter 1.5.5 I wanted to use this function: (sample-neg-binomial 10) which gives an unresolved symbol error. To be sure the project dependencies are up-to-date I re-ran Lein deps. Same error. This (:use [incanter core charts io datasets stats ]) is in my namespace function. A search in Stackoverflow indicates this works (sample-normal 100 :mean -2 :sd (sqrt 0.5)), but also gives an unresolved symbol; this post was 3 years ago. If anyone knows how to resolve this I would be grateful to find out?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for the question; please withdraw. Apparently my brain died for about 30 minutes.
All is well; the Incanter functions in the stats package work as expected.